# Editing a Facebook comment that was too long to post

Tags: facebook

I wrote a comment on FB that exceeded the 8000 character limit per error message, which said to shorten the comment.  A red box appears around comment, but won't let me edit.  Is there a way to actually edit the comment?

Comment: That's not the only problem with Facebook's comment limits. Until some time in April 2021, the limit of 8,000 characters was true. Not anymore. I have some high-quality comments and paste them into conversations as appropriate. The same under-8000-character comments that I entered before April 2021 are no longer accepted even though they are exactly the same as before and are fewer than 8,000 characters long. But it's even worse than that. The limit is not constant. Some comments longer than 7,000 characters are accepted and some fewer than 6,000 are rejected.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your activity log, You can find the post and edit it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution.

First, make sure you have the original comment saved (Notepad or whatever). Add another short comment, even just the word "Test" or simply a dot ("."). Refresh the page and the sticky old comment is gone. You may also want to delete the dummy comment to be nice. Now you can present the old comment in installments and beat the 8k chars limit.

Answer (score -1):

I would copy the text to a doc/word so it doesn't get lost. Edit and save in the doc, and create a new edited post from the text I edited outside of Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

Dealing with the same issue right now.

Lemino, here are some details.
When FB blocks a comment for being too long, and wraps the comment with a red line, there are no three dots next to it, as there are with any other comment. They only 'clickable' option is 'try again.' Which leads only to a repeat of the issue and a box suggesting 'try shortening your comment.'

Additionally, the comment can't be copied with the cursor in any way. No drag-and-click, and you're only able to see the first paragraph or so of the comment.

What's most annoying is that Facebook could stop users in the middle of a comment  by halting the appearance of new text, along with a warning, e.g. "You have reached the 8,000 character limit. Please edit or shorten your comment." But they don't. Many other sites - newspapers, magazines,blogs -use such a warning to limit length. But with FB you are in the same fix whether you write 8,001 or 16,000 characters. Essentially, the comment is locked: you can't edit it, you can't 'remove' it, but neither can you post it or even read it yourself.

It's maddening.

Answer (score -1):

I did 9000 character comment on a Facebook post, You just have to log in to Facebook through your laptop or desktop and visit that post and comment on it, lol, that's it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).